# Javascript API Call JIRA Cloud + Basic Auth does not work and receiving Access-Control-Allow-Origin Error

Tags: javascript, rest, cors, jira, jira-rest-api

I have a question reagrding how to call make a  API call for JIRA Cloud API using Basic Authorization.
I want to get my Issues and then edit some values through REST API.

I follow some tutorials and examples

https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/intro/

I took a look in
https://support.atlassian.com/user-management/docs/create-and-update-groups/

I think I must give premissions in the as I read here  https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/oauth-2-3lo-apps/

and for the basic authorization I shall get a api token here use the  https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/basic-auth-for-rest-apis/

I use this code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>
console.log("called function httpGetRequest");  
        
    
    let url = 'https://my-domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/TEST-2';
    let user = '<my email address>';
    let password = '<basic api token>';
    let pass_base64 = btoa(password);

    let auth_buff = user+":"+password;
    let auth = btoa(auth_buff);
    

  
    console.log ("auth : "+auth);

    
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

 
    xhr.open("GET", url);
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    


    
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + auth);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');


    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        console.log( 'Response: '+ xhr.status + ' -  '+xhr.responseText);
       if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
          console.log(xhr.status);
          console.log(xhr.responseText);
       }};



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I get always the error:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://my-domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/TEST-2. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

XHR GET https://my-domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/TEST-2.

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://my-domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/TEST-2. . (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: *What can I do?* Start by familiarising yourself with the CORS protocol. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS is a good start.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Yes maybe I formulated that wrong. I mean "What I am doing wrong", because I with the same method I get a GET call from other APIs.

Comment: If you're familiar with CORS, why are you setting an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on a request? That header is a response header; it should come from the server, not from the client. Also, `+` is not a valid value for that header. Did you mean `*`?

Comment: Thank you again for your answer. I do not say I am familiar with CORS. (as far I know, after reading the developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)  It shall be set in the server side. I remove  the Access-Control-Allow-Origin from the code. As you appointed is wrong. But I am still getting the same error.  :-(

Comment: No problem; we're all here to learn. I just wanted to check what you understand or not. Are you even sure that the target of your request is configured/configurable for CORS?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I create the request in a plain js  request.js and then with "node request.js" I get a response properly. With a script definition in the html was not possible.